# Why won't cmd.cmdloop stop with cmd.onecmd in Python?

Tags: python, cmd

While using cmd for python I have a method named do_exit which returns True to make the cmdloop quit.

I try to call  `cmd.onecmd('exit')`, but when the command `exit` runs, the cmdloop does not exit.

There are also no errors. The `do_exit` method is getting called because `Exiting me.` does get printed. That makes it all the more mysterious.

I have looked at the source of the `cmd module`, and I can't find what the problem is. Considering `cmd.onecmd` probably gets called on all commands I feel like calling it directly should work.

I had also tried to use `cmd.postcmd` with the return value of `cmd.onecmd`, but that didn't work either.

The specific line is near the bottom of this code in the `quit_all` function.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cmd
from gi.repository import Gtk
import threading

class WindowWidget(object):

    def __init__(self):
        win = Gtk.Window()
        win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
        win.show_all()
        self.window = win;
    def create_button(self):
        self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Click Here")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)
        self.window.add(self.button)
        self.window.show_all()

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        print 'something happened'
        return


class InteractiveShell(cmd.Cmd):
    #Simple command processor example.
    prompt='>'
    def __init__(self, gtk_object):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        # or cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.gtk_object = gtk_object

    def do_greet(self, line):
        print "hello"

    def do_setbutton(self, line):
        self.gtk_object.create_button()

    def do_exit(self, line):
        """Close the gtk main loop, and return True to exit cmd."""

        print 'Exiting me.'
        return True

    def postloop(self):
        print 'Closing window.'
        if Gtk.main_level() > 0:
            Gtk.main_quit()



def worker(num, s):
    """thread worker function"""
    #print 'Worker: %s' % num
    s.cmdloop()
    return

def worker2(num):
    Gtk.main()

threads = []



if __name__ == '__main__':

    ww = WindowWidget()
    mainshell = InteractiveShell(ww)
    threads = []

    def quit_all(event, user_data):
        print 'x out of window. Trying to exit shell.'
        #offending line cmdloop won't exit
        r = mainshell.onecmd('exit')
        return False

    ww.window.connect("delete-event", quit_all)

    t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(1, mainshell))
    threads.append(t)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=worker2, args=(2,))
    threads.append(t2)
    t.start()
    t2.start()
```

**Edit** After playing with the code, and running the method `cmd.onecmd` from inside the cmd object itself I see that the method does work. It's apparent that it's the threading that's probably the problem. Something is causing the `exit` to not working inside `gtk events` specifically the `delete-event`. I still don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Could you show us more of your code?

Comment: @xander Do you know what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Based on the other answer here I tried to `daemonize` the cmd thread, and `sys.exit` from the program. Didn't work. The window froze, and made me kill it. I don't know why this happened because I don't know what I'm doing yet. I decide to not `daemonize` any threads.
2. Next based on the advice from another related answer on a related question I posted I tried placing the Gtk.main in the main thread instead of its own thread. `Gtk window` opens, but there's no cmd interface. No it doesn't work, but...
3. I move `Gtk.main` to the very bottom of the program. Now everything opens. Now I can close everything with sys.exit, but now something else. The terminal input is blank. First I think that it's not accepting input. After some research on the great google I find some other SO questions about the same thing, but it turns out that the terminal is accepting input. It's just invisible.
4. As suggested I try `os.system('reset')` which now works. Yay! But it's an aweful shut down with the window hanging for a few seconds after the terminal input is already reset.
5. I search the internet determined. In the boondocks of the internet on another forum I find `stty echo`, and `stty sane` terminal commands. They both work to fix the problem. I choose `os.system('stty sane')`.

Everything works now. To be up to date I turned `os.system('stty sane')` to `Popen('stty sane', shell=True)`. Other people were saying that an application will modify the terminal settings, and that will make input not echo. It was probably cmd doing it. `stty sane` is the clear solution.

Here's the code with all the solutions. Ugh. It was way simpler than I expected.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cmd
from gi.repository import Gtk
import threading

"""
The bottom of this file has all the goodies for this solution.
Scroll down to see the cool stuff.
"""
class WindowWidget(object):

    def __init__(self):
        win = Gtk.Window()
        win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
        win.show_all()
        self.window = win;
    def create_button(self):
        self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Click Here")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)
        self.window.add(self.button)
        self.window.show_all()

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        print 'something happened'
        return


class InteractiveShell(cmd.Cmd):
    #Simple command processor example.
    prompt='>'
    def __init__(self, gtk_object):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        # or cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.gtk_object = gtk_object

    def do_greet(self, line):
        print "hello"

    def do_setbutton(self, line):
        """
        Using GLib.idle_add to insert a callback into the Gtk loop.
        This makes synchronizing the main thread where gtk is at, and
        this second thread easier.
        """
        GLib.idle_add(self.idle_setbutton)

    def idle_setbutton(self):
        self.gtk_object.create_button()

    def do_exit(self, line):
        """Close the gtk main loop, and return True to exit cmd."""

        print 'Exiting me.'
        return True

    def postloop(self):
        print 'Closing window.'
        if Gtk.main_level() > 0:
            Gtk.main_quit()



def worker(s):
    s.cmdloop()
    return

#isn't required  
#def worker2(num):
#    Gtk.main()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    ww = WindowWidget()
    mainshell = InteractiveShell(ww)
    #This list is superfluous
    #threads = []

    def quit_all(event, user_data):
        print 'x out of window. Trying to exit shell.'
        #I don't know if the next line is needed.
        #It's here just in case.
        Gtk.main_quit()
        #offending line cmdloop won't exit
        #but now it will because of sys.exit
        r = mainshell.onecmd('exit')

        #Problem found with sys.exit
        #When this program closes terminal input is working, but
        #it's blank. Here comes the fix.
        #Works, but it is messy -> os.system('reset')
        #Does not work -> Popen('reset', shell=True)
        #The command 'stty sane' is the best way to keep the
        #terminal from having blank input after closing.
        #os.system('stty sane')
        #Actually use Popen for this.
        Popen('stty sane', shell=True)
        #alternatively
        #os.system('stty echo')
        #sys.exit can only exit the whole program from the main thread.
        sys.exit(0)
        #Threads are closing, and so is the window.
        #This is a clean close.
        return False

    ww.window.connect("delete-event", quit_all)

    t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(mainshell))
    #No need to create a thread for Gtk.main
    #threads.append(t)
    #t2 = threading.Thread(target=worker2, args=(2,))
    #threads.append(t2)
    t.start()
    #t2.start()
    #Gtk.main needs to be called after the second thread is started.
    #This will keep Gtk from blocking the second thread.
    #Gtk.main loop in the python main thread is easier to deal with
    #to make sure that work for Gtk will get finished.
    #Can use GLib.idle_add to insert functions, and methods into
    #the Gtk loop.
    Gtk.main()
```

I did not try to pipe input from a Gtk field. Maybe another time.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can understand where the problem is ... but I have no simple fix for it. Calling `onecommand('exit')` if a noop for the `cmdloop`. From the `cmd` module point of view, it starts a `cmdloop` the `cmdloop` repetedly calls commands and looks at the return value of the commands it launches. Something like :

```
while True:
   cr = do_cmd
   if cr:
        break
```

If you call `do_cmd` outside of the loop, nobody cares, and the loop is still waiting. It is exactly what happens in your program : you calls `do_exit`, it executes with no error, but you have not interrupted the loop.

Now for the fixes (I do not have Gtk installed so I could not test myself) :

Quick and dirty : you could make the thread carrying the `cmdloop` a daemon thread. When you want to close your program, clean everything else (your windows) and exit. The thread (and its loop) should be abruptly stopped.

Nicer, but longer. Do not give `sys.stdin` to the `cmd` but only a pipe. Use a field from one of your windows to get the input commands, and write it to the pipe. When you want to stop, **write 'exit' to the pipe**. The loop, will read it, execute your `do_exit` method, get a `True` as return and exit. But I must acknowledge that the `cmd` module is loosing a part of its interest ...

As I do not know what you really want to do with in your application I cannot imagine a more efficient solution. Maybe you should give more details about the general structure of what you want to do.

Comment: I want to make a gtk text area, and interact with that by sending commands through the terminal. The button adder is just a test. That is exactly what's happening. The return is not getting seen. It's strange because I used the method outside of the gtk event, and it stopped the cmd loop.

Comment: lol. I almost got it. I removed the thread for the gtk, and just placed the gtk.main after the other thread. Now when in shuts it works, but the terminal won't accept any characters now.

Answer (score 0):

In python3, you can do the following:

```py
interactor.cmdqueue.append("exit\n") #Where interactor is the object(Cmd)
print("Please press Enter to continue...")
```

The idea is that `cmdloop()` is hanging on `input()` (or will be hanging on `readline()` if you use `raw_input`=False). However, you can simply append to the commands queue it uses for playback. The problem is that you need an `Enter` to get it passed the `input()` part. Which makes sense, because otherwise, `Cmd` cannot give you the smooth intuitive interaction you're using it for.